# Adding WCF service behaviors with code

Tags: c#, wcf

I know I can add service behaviors with some XML configuration, but I'd like to do it with a piece of C#, similar how you can add endpoint behaviors. I'm not sure how to do that, though.

In other words, how can I add the debug behavior I've instantiated below?

```
var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService));
var endpoint = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof (MysService), 
    new WebHttpBinding(), new Uri(myURL));
endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
var debug = new ServiceDebugBehavior
{
    IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true
};
//WHAT DO I PUT HERE?
host.Open();
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
host.Description.Behaviors.Add(debug);
```

Comment: Thanks! It turns out I couldn't do .Add() because that behavior is already there. But this worked great: `host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior>().IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true`

Comment: What if this behavior is defined in confituration, but service in the code? How to add it to WCF host with code?

Answer (score 4):

Also you can write an atrribute for your service e.g.

```
[ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
public class Service1 : IServiceChild
```